# How to enhance the performance while dealing with two maps in Java

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have two maps - `Map<String, List<String>> input`, and another one is `Map<String, List<String>> output`.

input map

```
{A=[Apple.txt, Axe.txt, Aid.txt], B=[Ball.txt, Boy.txt,Box.txt], C=[Cow.txt,Cob.txt]}
```

output map

```
{A=[Apple.txt, Axe.txt, Aid.txt], B=[Ball.txt, Boy.txt]}
```

I need to find the missing key-value pair for output map.

```
 expected output - B= [Box.txt], C=[Cow.txt,Cob.txt]
```

I need to identify that the output map is missing Box.txt for B key and 'C' key-value pair is missing.

My current approach: I am using one forEach(time complexity `O(n)`) and one entry set stream(time complexity: `O(m)`) for two maps which cause `O(n*m)` time complexity.

```
inputMap.forEach((key,value) ->
    {
    final List<Path> countrifiedFolderList = outputFileMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains(key))
            .filter(files -> !files.getValue().contains(inputFile)).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (!countrifiedFolderList.isEmpty())
    {....do processing
    }
```

I need to enhance the performance issue as the map contains a huge number of data. I need to fetch the result in less than O(n*m) time complexity.

Comment: If the condition you have to look for is `entry.getKey().toString().contains(key)`, then you are going to need a much more sophisticated custom data structure that will be nontrivial to create.  If it could be `entry.getKey().equals(key)`, then it's a very different story.

Comment: The main goal here is two compare two maps  and find the missing key-value pair  in outputMap

Comment: why not have `A=[], B= [Box.txt], C=[Cow.txt,Cob.txt]` as the final result? That might simplify things to some extent, but without traversing each value in the list corresponding to each key in the input or output map, how do you plan to identify what is missing. The complete traversal would have to be `O(n*m)` or maybe you've chosen the data structure from your initial input such that all you are now left with is `n*m` traversals?

Comment: Also, note the complexity of traversing each element in the value `List` of size `n` and performing a `contains` in another `List` of size `l` would result in the complexity to be `n*l`. Using a `Set` there should help optimise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not:

```
map1.keySet().containsAll(map2.keySet());
```

**Update**

With one stream:

```
Map<String, List> result = input.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> !output.keySet().contains(entry.getKey()) ||
                !output.get(entry.getKey()).containsAll(entry.getValue()))
        .map(entry -> {
                List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue());
                List<String> current = output.get(entry.getKey());
                expected.removeAll(current != null ? current : List.of());
                return Map.entry(entry.getKey(), expected);
            })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

If you want to measure performance, I would suggest doing a micro-benchmark using your data-structure, sample size, hardware, etc.
If you are interest in micro-benchmark, I would suggest using [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: It returns a boolean value which I don't need. Instead, I need to identify the missing value of map2

Comment: Understood. Updated to achieve your goal with one stream

Comment: `Map<String, List> result = new HashMap<>(map1); map2.forEach((key,value) -> result.get(key).removeAll(value)); result.values().removeIf(Collection::isEmpty);`

Answer (score 0):

If they are TreeMaps, then their keys are already sorted.  You could walk both lists together in O(n).  Oboe's solution is the best you'll get with HashMaps, and will be O(n*log2(m)).

Answer (score 0):

Few things that could simplify the solution a bit more would be, considering the `output` map to be a `Map<String, Set<String>>` and then as the final result being able to treat keys which are present completely in the output map as empty `[]`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> lookUpExclusives(Map<String, List<String>> input,
                                                  Map<String, Set<String>> output) {
    return input.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue().stream()
                            .filter(val -> !output.getOrDefault(e.getKey(),
                                    Collections.emptySet()).contains(val))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
}
```

This would return `{A=[], B=[Box.txt], C=[Cow.txt, Cob.txt]}` from the method. In terms of the complexity, this would be `M` number of times for each element in the value of the entry of the input map and that for each of the `N` entries, so `O(N*M)` as well, but that should be the most possible optimization in runtime complexity.

Now that you've had this complex runtime, you can further chain another stream operation to filter entries which do not have any corresponding values left in the result (e.g. `A=[]`). This could be achieved by appending the following code to the above pipeline after the first `collect` :

```
.entrySet().stream()
.filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

It results in the complexity only as `O(N*M)` + `O(N)` which could effectively be expressed as `O(N*M)` only. The advantage over here is that you get the result in the format as you would have expected such as `{B=[Box.txt], C=[Cow.txt, Cob.txt]}`.